# Rebuild is deleting my .lib

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, rebuild

Im trying to merge 2 projects in visual studio and getting a LNK1181 error. I have searched on google and tried everything i came across but i simple cant solve the problem.

I am getting the following results:
Performing a *build* this succeeds.
Performing a *Rebuild* it fails with error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'a.dll'

Doing a build the output screen shows the dll is created and it is there in the folder.
Doing a rebuild the output screen shows the dll is created but then it is not in the folder. And then the rebuild results in the fail + the error LNK1181.

So what is wrong? What is different on a rebuild?

I can even see in the folder that the dll is beiing created and then removed again..

*I have 1 project that is the main project and creates the .exe, and it relies on a other project to run.

**Solution:**

I found the problem and is has nothing to do with the LNK error message i am getting.

Apparently a clean -> build is very different from doing just a rebuild. Mainly because i have multiple projects. When doing a clean -> build is first cleans all the files and then builds all the projects.

But doing a rebuild project A is beiing cleaned and build, then project B is beiing cleaned and build etc..

This way the lib generated bij A is beiing deleted. The solution for this is or just do a clean -> build. Or perform my own clean by deleting the files myself and then do a rebuild.

Also i dont feel like spending to much time on this issue when it is just a MSbuild "problem/bug" and doing a clean build is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

linker error is maybe due to some lib is missing.
firstly check whether you have the lib for a.dll,
then add correct path for the lib in Visual Studio.

Comment: But why is the "normal" build working? And the lib is beiing created by visual studio and then removed again resulting in the fail.